# Ionic map loads when i first enter the page but after navigating back it does not load

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I am working on a hiking app based on IONIC geolocation, i have been trying to load the map but it always works well for the first time but when i go back to other tabs and when i return to that map page the page goes blank.

> This is the code for the map-geolocation

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import {Navbar, NavController, NavParams, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import * as firebase from 'Firebase';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';
import {Hike} from "../../shared/hike";


declare var google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-Geoloc',
  templateUrl: 'Geoloc.html'
  })
export class Geoloc {

@ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
map: any;
markers = [];
ref = firebase.database().ref('geolocations/');
hike: Hike;

@ViewChild(Navbar) navBar: Navbar;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
          public navParams: NavParams,
          public platform: Platform,
          private geolocation: Geolocation,
          private device: Device) {

this.hike = navParams.get('data');


}

initMap() {
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {

  let mylocation = new 
  google.maps.LatLng(resp.coords.latitude,resp.coords.longitude);
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, {
    zoom: 15,
    center: mylocation
  });
 });
 google.maps.event.trigger(this.map, 'resize');
 let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
 watch.subscribe((data) => {
 this.deleteMarkers();
 this.updateGeolocation(this.device.uuid, 
 data.coords.latitude,data.coords.longitude);
 let updatelocation = new 
 google.maps.LatLng(data.coords.latitude,data.coords.longitude);
    let image = 'assets/imgs/blue-bike.png';
    this.addMarker(updatelocation,image);
    this.setMapOnAll(this.map);
  });
} 

 addMarker(location, image) {
   let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: location,
   map: this.map,
   icon: image
  });
  this.markers.push(marker);
 }

 setMapOnAll(map) {
 for (var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++) {
 this.markers[i].setMap(map);
   }
 }

 clearMarkers() {
 this.setMapOnAll(null);
 }

 deleteMarkers() {
   this.clearMarkers();
   this.markers = [];
 }

 updateGeolocation(uuid, lat, lng) {
     let timestamp = Date();
     if(localStorage.getItem('mykey')) {


firebase.database().ref('geolocations/'+localStorage.getItem('mykey')).set({
    uuid: uuid,
    latitude: lat,
    longitude : lng,
    timestamp : timestamp
  });
} else {
  let newData = this.ref.push();
  newData.set({
    uuid: uuid,
    latitude: lat,
    longitude: lng,
    timestamp : timestamp
  });
  console.log(newData.key);
  localStorage.setItem('mykey', newData.key);
  }
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
 this.navBar.backButtonClick = (e:UIEvent)=>{
   // todo something
   this.navCtrl.pop();
 }

 this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.initMap();
 });
 this.ref.on('value', resp => {
  this.deleteMarkers();
  snapshotToArray(resp).forEach(data => {
    if (data.uuid !== this.device.uuid){
      var currentTime = new Date().getSeconds();
      if (data.timestamp + 25 <= currentTime) {
        let image = 'assets/imgs/green-bike.png';
        let updatelocation = new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude, data.longitude);
        this.addMarker(updatelocation, image);
        this.setMapOnAll(this.map);
      }
      else {
        let image = 'assets/imgs/blue-bike.png';
        let updatelocation = new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude, data.longitude);
        this.addMarker(updatelocation, image);
        this.setMapOnAll(this.map);
      }
    }
    else {
      let image = 'assets/imgs/blue-bike.png';
      let updatelocation = new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude, data.longitude);
      this.addMarker(updatelocation, image);
      this.setMapOnAll(this.map);
      }
    });
  });

}


}

export const snapshotToArray = snapshot => {
 let returnArr = [];

snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
  let item = childSnapshot.val();
  item.key = childSnapshot.key;
  returnArr.push(item);
});

 return returnArr;
};
```

I have tried some solutions by changing the lifecycle elements and by using this.maps.remove(); but they dont work

Comment: inspect your app using chrome device debug, and post the error too

Comment: Native: tried calling Device.uuid, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator      ----  It just gives this error but it is same on the android device even when it is able to get the device uuid

Answer (score 0):

When you leave the map page after it is first shown, the original DOM element the map was attached to is destroyed. 
Consequently the native Google Maps UI element is attached to a non-existent DOM element when you "return" to your map page, since under the hood Ionic is actually recreating a new set of DOM elements for your map page when you revisit it.

The solution is to call [setDiv()](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/tree/master/v2.0.0/class/Map/setDiv) on subsequent page shows after you initally create the map on the first page show.
This will update the native UI element to attach to the newly created DOM element.

In the context of your code:

```
export class Geoloc {

    mapInitialised = false;

    ionViewDidLoad() {

        if(this.mapInitialised){
            this.map.setDiv(this.mapElement.nativeElement);
        }else{
            this.platform.ready().then(() => {
                this.initMap();
                this.mapInitialised = true;
            });
        }
    }
}
```